# Shortcut works, but properties dialog says target name is invalid

Tags: windows, shortcuts

I created a shortcut (in C:\Users\Public\Desktop) to a text file. I then right-clicked it and selected Properties. This opened the Properties Shortcut tab. I want to grant another user permission to edit the shortcut, but when I try to switch to the Security tab, I get:
[Problem with Shortcut: The name ... is not valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeWI7.png)

The shortcut works, opening the file, C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\create_project_tips.txt, in Notepad, when I click it, but the properties dialog doesn't like it.

Any ideas what is wrong?

In answer to a comment, the .txt file is/was already set to allow other users to both write and read it. I want to allow the short cut to also be modifiable by others.

Comment: does it work if the txt file is stored outside of a user profile? I believe its telling you that the logged in user does not have access to the file in its present location. does that sound right? also you need to grant access to the File, not the shortcut. the shortcut should be accessible just by virtue of being part of the public profile.

Comment: @Frank Thomas: The .txt file is also set to write and read. I want to also allow the shortcut to be modified by others.